# Trying to combine two arrays doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to combine two select boxes into one. Here's the code:

```
//Selectbox 1
<?php $aCities = City::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
<?php if(count($aCities) > 0 ) { ?>
    <select id="dropdowncities">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Select your location...')?></option>
        <?php foreach($aCities as $city) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?>"><?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?>
            </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>


//Selectbox 2
<?php $aRegions = Region::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
<?php if(count($aRegions) > 0 ) { ?>
    <select id="dropdownregions">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Select your Region...')?></option>
        <?php foreach($aRegions as $region) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $region['s_name'] ; ?>"></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

As it is now both select boxes work fine and i get the correct results/values in them. But when i try to combine them into one single select box, like at the code below i get no results at all:

```
//Combine two select boxes
<?php $aRegions = Region::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
<?php $aCities = City::newInstance()->listAll(); ?>
<?php $cityandregion = array_combine($aRegions, $aCities); ?>
<?php if(count($aCities) > 0 ) { ?>
    <select id="dropdowncitiesregions">
        <option value=""><?php _e('Select your city and region...')?></option>
        <?php foreach($cityandregion as $city=>$region) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $city['s_name'] ; ?><?php echo $region['s_name'] ; ?>"><?php echo $cityandregion['s_name'] ; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
<?php } ?>
```

What i 'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:i get this message in debug file-> "PHP Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements"

Comment: _“What i 'm doing wrong?”_ - you appear to be developing without having proper PHP error reporting enabled - otherwise, that should have given you an error to begin with. So go and enable it first of all now please.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no reason to open and close PHP (using `<? php` and `?>`) on every row if there's multiple rows with PHP. That just makes the code way harder to read.

Comment: @Nick question edited its array_combine not array_shift

Comment: What do you mean by _"its array_combine not array_shift"_? Isn't the posted code a copy/paste of your real code? If not, then please copy/paste your actual code since rewrites can contain other issues your actual code don't, and the other way around.

Comment: @04FS you 're right. I get this message: "PHP Warning:  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements" i am updating the question now

Comment: @Nick as i wrote in my comment above it is array_combine, i updated the code in my question.

Comment: I guess your problem is you have less regions than cities. You need to figure out how to join the two together to get values which are already combined.

Comment: Correct. 10 Regions and 120 cities.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i meant that the real code is "array_combine" i updated the question. The code you see in my question is the real code from the file i work on.

Comment: Show us some examples of what those two arrays actually contain. Currently it does not appear as if using array_combine would make any sense even remotely here.

Comment: If it's 10 regions and 120 cities then I assume you want a multidimensional array? You should include some sample data to your question. This is getting confusing

Comment: You need an associative array that will have the regions as the keys and the cities in them but to do so, you need a reference of the Region for each city in your data. Do you have any samples? And also, you don't have to add <?php ... ?> in each line of your code!

Comment: If you don't then why not just simply have two select box? One for the region and one for the city?

Comment: @MichaelT I 'm working on that based on all comments i received. Thank you all. I 'll update the code when i finish.

Comment: See my answer, did a little example for 2 select boxes

Comment: Thank you for your time @MichaelT. Unforunately didnt work. I need to have only one selectbox combines city & region it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $cityandregion = array(
        "cities" => Region::newInstance()->listAll(),
        "regions" => City::newInstance()->listAll()
    ); 
    if(count($cityandregion["cities"]) > 0 && count($cityandregion["regions"])) {
        // Regions..
        $html = "<select id=\"dropdownregions\">";
        $html .= "<option value=\"\">('Select your region...')</option>";
        foreach($cityandregion["regions"] as $k => $region) {
            $html .= "<option value=\"" . $region['s_name'] . "\">" . $region['s_name'] . "</option>";
        }
        $html .= "</select></ br>";

        // Cities..
        $html = "<select id=\"dropdowncities\">";
        $html .= "<option value=\"\">('Select your city...')</option>";
        foreach($cityandregion["cities"] as $k => $city) {
            $html .= "<option value=\"" . $city['s_name'] . "\">" . $city['s_name'] . "</option>";
        }
        $html .= "</select></ br>";

        echo $html;
    }
?>
```